# someone decrypt double bracket (php) notation for me?

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php [[add_menu_page|add_menu_page]]( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function, $icon_url, $position ); ?>
```

how does this [[add_menu_page|add_menu_page]] work? and what is the underlying logic?

ref. http://codex.wordpress.org/Adding_Administration_Menus

Comment: rupert thx for the edit, but my question is not about wordpress. i'm curious how php interprets that statement.

Comment: PHP does not interpret the statement. It is a bug specific to Wordpress documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the Wordpress documentation run on a wiki? Because on most wikis (at least, of the MediaWiki variety), the [[ | ]] syntax is used to describe a link to another wiki page. That is probably just a link to the page about add_menu_page(). You can just read it like this:

```
<?php add_menu_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function, $icon_url, $position ); ?>
```

I checked the page and it isn't a link--so was probably copied incorrectly from a wiki at some point, because that definitely looks like a MediaWiki link.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bug in the documentation.

If you wish to use the add_menu_page function then you just type `add_menu_page()`.

Comment: I think this is the case considering the correct usage shown on: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page

Answer (score 0):

Often in documentation [a|b] is a means of telling the reader that you can use either a or b.. in this case I'd say it is an error in the documentation.